# how to share Data between cross modules in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have two module called **"uploadModule"** and **"graphModule"** in the same page **uploadModule**  browse data and save it on services   **(sharedDataObject)** and I want to share this amount of data to anther module **(graphModule)**

```js
var uploadModule = angular.module('uploadModule', ['ngRoute']);
uploadModule.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when('/',
                    {
                        controller: 'dataSetController',
                        templateUrl: 'view1.html'
                    })
            .when('/view2',
                    {
                        controller: 'compineGraphsWithData',
                        templateUrl: 'view2.html'
                    })
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})
});

uploadModule.service('sharedDataObject', function () {
 
        this.getDataObject= function () {
            return this.dataObject;
        };
        this.setDataObject= function (value) {
            this.dataObject = value;
        };
   
});//this service to share Data Object between controlles(graphs)

uploadModule.controller('dataSetController', dataSetController);//load data set and but it on sharedDataObject service
function dataSetController($scope, sharedDataObject) {
    $scope.datasetfile;
    var file;
    $scope.getDataSetFile = function (files) {
        file = files[0];
        $scope.datasetfile = file.name;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (evt) {
            var result = evt.target.result;
            var Json;
            Json = CSV2JSON(result);
            dataset = JSON.parse(Json);
            sharedDataObject.setDataObject(dataset);
            console.log(dataset);
              
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
        $scope.$apply();
    };
}
;

var graphModule = angular.module("graphModule", ['uploadModule']);
            graphModule.controller('createGraph', createGraph);
            function createGraph($scope ,sharedDataObject ) {
                $scope.Scatter = function () {
                    console.log(sharedDataObject.getDataobject());
                };
            }
            ;//compineGraphsWithData and fire graph function
 angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("App2"),['graphModule']);
```

```html
<input type="file"  id="dataset" name='file' onchange="angular.element(this).scope().getDataSetFile(this.files)" />
```

Answer (score 2):

the function name seems not right:

```
console.log(sharedDataObject.getDataobject());
```

It should be:

```
console.log(sharedDataObject.getDataObject());
```

**Edit**:
I don't know, everything seems fine to me. Angularjs services can be used to share data between controllers, even if they are belong to different modules.
Since I don't know you full script, I make up a example base on your sample code. Here is it:

```
    <html><head>
    <style>        
    </style>    
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="graphModule">
    <div ng-controller="dataSetController">
    <input type="file" id="dataset" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().getDataSetFile(this.files)">    
    </div>  
    <div ng-controller="createGraph">
    <button ng-click="Scatter()">Click me</button>
    </div>
</div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>

var uploadModule = angular.module('uploadModule', []);

uploadModule.service('sharedDataObject', function () {

  this.getDataObject = function () {
    return this.dataObject;
  };
  this.setDataObject = function (value) {
    this.dataObject = value;
  };

});//this service to share Data Object between controlles(graphs)

uploadModule.controller('dataSetController', dataSetController);//load data set and but it on sharedDataObject service
function dataSetController($scope, sharedDataObject) {
  $scope.datasetfile;
  var file;
  $scope.getDataSetFile = function (files) {
    file = files[0];
    $scope.datasetfile = file.name;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
      var result = evt.target.result;
      var Json;
      //Json = CSV2JSON(result);
      Json = result;
      //dataset = JSON.parse(Json);
      dataset = Json;
      sharedDataObject.setDataObject(dataset);
      console.log(dataset);

    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
    $scope.$apply();
  };
}
;

var graphModule = angular.module("graphModule", ['uploadModule']);
graphModule.controller('createGraph', createGraph);
function createGraph($scope, sharedDataObject) {
  $scope.Scatter = function () {
    console.log(sharedDataObject.getDataObject());
  };
}

;//compineGraphsWithData and fire graph function
// angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("App2"),['graphModule']);

    </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: it still not work, console print undefined 
I think we need concept like static Module

Comment: Have a look at edited code, it works for me. Sorry I can't firgure out what the problem in your code.

Comment: btw, make sure that CSV2JSON and JSON.parse function didn't return an undefined value.

Answer (score 1):

The way to share data between controllers using a service follows this pattern:
http://embed.plnkr.co/ohkXfy/preview

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.service('sharedModels', [function () {
    'use strict';

    // Shared Models
    this.data = {breakfast: 'eggs'};

}]);

myApp.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', 'sharedModels', function($scope, sharedModels) {

    $scope.myBreakfast = sharedModels.data;
}]);

myApp.controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope', 'sharedModels', function($scope, sharedModels) {

    $scope.yourBreakfast = sharedModels.data
}]);

myApp.controller('Ctrl3', ['$scope', 'sharedModels', function($scope, sharedModels) {

    $scope.ourBreakfast = sharedModels.data;
}]);`
```

Answer (score 1):

You should extract the common state into its own module, and add it as a dependency in both modules. Then you can access the same shared state in both modules.

EDIT: I made an example of what I mean in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ODoF5vtMZk4WKO8ApsIE).

So you make one module which contains the service that both modules need:

```
(function(){
  angular.module("sharedData", [])
    .service("sharedService", function(){
      this.getSharedData = function(){
        return this.sharedObject;
      };

      this.setSharedData = function(newData){
        this.sharedObject = newData;
      };
    });
}());
```

Then you make this module a dependency of the modules that need it:

```
(function(){
  angular.module("firstModule", ["sharedData"])
    .controller("firstCtrl", function($scope, sharedService){
      $scope.get = function(){
        $scope.data = sharedService.getSharedData();
      };
    });
}());
(function(){
  angular.module("secondModule", ["sharedData"])
    .controller("secondCtrl", function($scope, sharedService){
      $scope.set = function(){
        sharedService.setSharedData("Test");
      };
    });
}());
```

Ask ahead if you have more questions.

Comment: can you give me more explanation please? @juunas